# Hard lock-up and skype window shows up after reboot

Tags: 11.04, skype

I just had a hard lock-up not even a Alt+Shift+PrtSC+R+S+E+I+U+B could solve, and when rebooting, the skype window was asking me for the userid and password, which is weird, because I had entered them before.

I am wondering if skype was trying to update something that caused the lock-up, and that's why I have to enter the userid/pwd again on reboot.

Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this on a few difference occasions - I haven't figured out why either.

So the answer to your question is that "Yes, other people have seen it".

As for the lockup, if you could report that bug (more on that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)) that'd be great.